# cannot upload data to s3 through lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to extract data from trust advisor through lambda function and upload to s3. Some part of the function executes the append module on the data. However, that module block throws error. That specific block is

```
try:
                check_summary = support_client.describe_trusted_advisor_check_summaries(
                                checkIds=[checks['id']])['summaries'][0]
                if check_summary['status'] != 'not_available':
                    checks_list[checks['category']].append(
                       [checks['name'], check_summary['status'],
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesProcessed']),
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesFlagged']),
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesSuppressed']),
                        str(check_summary['resourcesSummary']['resourcesIgnored'])  
                        ])
                else:
                    print("unable to append checks")
                       
            except:
                print('Failed to get check: ' +  checks['name'])
                traceback.print_exc()
```

The error logs

```
unable to append checks
```

I'm new to Python. So, unsure of how to check for trackback stacks under else: statement. Also, am I doing anything wrong in the above ? Plz help

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the `s3_upload` function anywhere, also the code is invalid since it has file_name variable in it which is not initialized.

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes suggested. I am now promoted to a new error now as below:
"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the PutObject operation: All access to this object has been disabled"

kindly suggest if im incorrectly specifying any parameters in the above code

Answer (score 0):

I've observed your script-

- `traceback.print_exc()` This should be executed before the return statement so that the python compiler can identify the obstacles/errors
- `if __name__ == '__main__':`
  `lambda_handler`
  This will work only if is used to execute some code only if the file was run directly, and not imported.
- According to the documentation the first three parameters of the `put_object` method,
  `def put_object(self, bucket_name, object_name, data, length,`
  Fix your parameters of put_object.
- you're not using `s3_upload` in your lambda.

Comment: Thank you! I made the changes suggested. I am now promoted to a new error now as below:
"botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the PutObject operation: All access to this object has been disabled"

kindly suggest if im incorrectly specifying any parameters in the above code